# Animate logo on hover with pseudo elements :before and :after?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, hover, transition

I have playing with my logo and trying to achieve to get two hover animation with pseudo elements, and I have got some results, but have some glitches (if you move cursor a bit below logo, letter "B", you will see it), showing again `.logo a:after {content: "ogosavljev"}` or if you idea, how to avoid this second div -  please share it :)

Or to animate it with jquery?

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div class="wrap">    
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="/"><img src="http://s28.postimg.org/mqb5ghrwt/letter_B_blue_hover_me.png" /></a>
        <div class="front">
            <a href="/">front-end designer &amp; developer</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

### CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Francois+One);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arbutus+Slab);

html {
    font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
    font-size:17px;
    line-height:1.5;
}

.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.logo a {
    font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 650px;
}

.front a:after {
   color: #6FCCE1; 
}

.logo a:hover + .front a {
    font-family: 'Arbutus Slab', serif;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #6FCCE1;
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0.6s;
    transform: translate(41%,-62px);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    width: 650px;
}

.logo a:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #71CCE2;
    content: "ogosavljev";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    height: 23px;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    vertical-align: top;
}
.logo a span, .logo a:after {
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.logo a:hover:after, .logo a:focus:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-8%,-20px);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
```

Example you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bogosavljev/eLots246/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use data attribute to access him with your pseudo classes, for example

```
<a href="#" data-hover="some other text or font icons">some</a>

a:before{
   content: attr(data-hover);
}
```

so you can write "front-end designer & developer" and get him in :before

here is great example which is using this technique http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/

When you hover on a elem your pseudo class get value which you set in content of it, so you have two words which should be displayed, in:before will be "ogosavljev" and in :after will be "front-end designer & developer" which should be in data attribute of a elem, all other is question about position those classes and animate, good luc

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)** (MDN) but it's compatible wih IE11+ so no IE10...

But first, the source of the problem is visible if you add outlines: http://jsfiddle.net/eLots246/2/
The tagline passes between cursor and image so `.logo > a` isn't hovered anymore!

Add pointer-events on tagline and it's *invisible* for the cursor (sort of): http://jsfiddle.net/eLots246/3/

Beware of caniuse.com : there are 2 entries for [pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events), the related one is for HTML, not SVG ;)

Comment: You have a point, but do you have solution, or other approach?

Comment: [This is a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/eLots246/3/), for IE11+, as linked and stated in my answer

Comment: @FelipeAls Can you check this and suggests to me how can I achieve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923436/on-hover-after-element-move-to-current-div