# On hover :after element move to current div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to move pseudo-element when we hover on the current div. Here pink color div I want to move vertically in front of the currently hovered div. Can anyone suggest to me  how can I achieve this output

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".timeline-entry").hover(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.timeline-entry.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
  });
});
```

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.timeline-entry.right-aligned {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: blue;
}

.timeline-entry.left-aligned {
  float: left;
}

.timeline:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
}


/* .timeline-entry:hover .timeline:nth-child(1) .timeline:after {
  top: 100px;
} */

.timeline-entry.current {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timeline">
  <article class="timeline-entry right-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry left-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry right-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry left-aligned"></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to move that pink element? Because  if not, then it can be done easily with only CSS for every hovered div.

Comment: @Gil Yes I want to move :after pink element top to bottom

Comment: Couldn't you do this by using :after or :before on the children instead? It's tricky to move it on the parent based on child position. Only way I can think of is write into a style tag with js. I just did some attempts using css `attr()` function but it has limited support for properties other than `content`

Comment: Or make it an actual dom element instead of using `:after`? You could even animate a real element

Comment: @Husna Here's the problem, moving the pseudo element will require calculating its absolute position in relation to the hovered element, and it will break the moment the page size changes, so this will require adding a resize listener. A more reliable solution is to set it as a non-pseudo element and add it as a child to the hovered element, but if the end result is showing the same element on hover, setting the `:after` selector will do it nicely.

Comment: @ Gil  Can you make a snippet of code to show what you're suggesting to me.

Comment: @charlietfl Can we hard fix and do like nth-child(1) hover move :after something like this

Comment: Not at all clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is on the assumption that you don't need the exact same element to move and only interested in showing it on hover. I'm still not sure what you actually want. This is done with pure CSS without the need for any JS code.

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
article {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline-entry.right-aligned {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: blue;
}
.timeline-entry.left-aligned {
  float: left;
}
.timeline-entry:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.timeline-entry:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <article class="timeline-entry right-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry left-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry right-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry left-aligned"></article>
</div>
```

I also changed the pseudo-element height to 100% since it's now contained by the article element.

**UPDATE**

This is another answer, followed by the question update.

```css
article {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
article div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
.timeline-entry.right-aligned div {
  float: right;
  background: blue;
}
.timeline-entry.left-aligned div {
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
.timeline-entry div:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
.timeline-entry div:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <article class="timeline-entry right-aligned"><div></div></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry left-aligned"><div></div></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry right-aligned"><div></div></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry left-aligned"><div></div></article>
</div>
```

There are other ways to reach this result. I've kept the CSS only approach.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. but I want to move div top to bottom in the same direction vertically.

Comment: well at least this is a good example why a question should be asked as clearly as possible. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect this is what exactly I want to do. but when i add `transition: all 0.5s linear;` div come from left

Comment: Please be more specific. Add to where? What div comes from left? If you want a proper answer you need to give clear information.

Comment: I'm trying to add smooth transition like div slightly moving from top to bottom `.timeline-entry div:hover::after` to this class I added `transition: all 0.5s linear;`

Comment: Sorry, this will require a whole different approach to accommodate this new requirement and you'll have to sit down with a developer to build it.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230721/discussion-between-husna-and-gil).